# error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getReport') Deno+vite

Tags: vue.js, vite, deno

I am using Ubuntu. I tray install deno-vue along this docs https://docs.deno.com/runtime/tutorials/how_to_with_npm/vue
I am getting weird error.

```
Task dev deno run -A --node-modules-dir npm:vite
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getReport')
    at isMusl (file:///home/bbabinski-a/Documents/Udemy/quasar-vite/node_modules/.deno/rollup@4.6.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:5:30)
    at getPackageBase (file:///home/bbabinski-a/Documents/Udemy/quasar-vite/node_modules/.deno/rollup@4.6.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:53:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///home/bbabinski-a/Documents/Udemy/quasar-vite/node_modules/.deno/rollup@4.6.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:28:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///home/bbabinski-a/Documents/Udemy/quasar-vite/node_modules/.deno/rollup@4.6.0/node_modules/rollup/dist/native.js:81:4)
    at Module._compile (node:module:733:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:module:747:10)
    at Module.load (node:module:658:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:module:539:12)
    at Module.require (node:module:677:19)
    at require (node:module:791:16)
```

My setup:
-deno 1.38.4
Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish

What am I doing wrong? please help!!

I was trying to install Deno + Vite

Comment: This is Deno issue. It can fail when the compatibility with Node is expected. Potentially the doc was written for older package versions that didn't have this problem. See https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/21355

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed recently on https://github.com/denoland/deno/pull/21373

It should work on future Deno releases.

For now, you can specify an earlier version of Vite, like this:

```
deno run -A --node-modules-dir npm:vite@^4.5.1
```

It's probably better than using the monkey-patch approach.

It worked for me. Note that this issue only affects Linux systems.

Answer (score 0):

With Deno 1.39.0 this problem is fixed! :D